# Forms Authentication for some subdomains but not others

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication

Is it possible if a user is  authenticated on **sitedomain.com**, that he will be authenticated on **www.sitedomain.com** but not authenticated on **sub.sitedomain.com**  using Forms Authentication?

Comment: http://davestechshop.net/FormsAuthCookiesAndSubdomainNames2

Comment: Cookies on a domain apply to *all* subdomains. If you only want the cookie on one subdomain, set the cookie on just that subdomain.